# java gwt apply css style for IFrameElement

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have an

```
IFrameElement fie;
```

for which I need to apply the css style:

```
p{
        font-family: arial,sans-serif;
        color: #666666;
        font-size: 9px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1px;
        font-weight: bolder;
}
```

But I just find a way to GET the style and not SET it

```
Style s = fie.getContentDocument().getBody().getStyle();
```

How can I apply the css for this IFrameElement?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fie.getContentDocument().getBody().setId("myframe");
```

and in the css file:

```
p, .myframe p {
        font-family: arial,sans-serif;
        color: #666666;
        font-size: 9px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1px;
        font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Comment: No that does not work, I don't receive any errors but nothing happens

Comment: What about setting the style name for the iframe? I mean `fie.setId("myframe");`